# PHP load SESSION design on new page

Tags: php, session

I looked around and not having much luck finding similar issue. Please link possible duplicates if any, suggestions from previous posts would help.

**Scenario:**

When user open a `create.php` page, I set the `$_SESSION['id']` to an ID on that page. If user refresh the browser, the content can be picked up. It works great since everything is linked to *sql database* as it gets updated.

Issue comes up when the same user click on another `create.php` page at the same time that the initial `create.php` is already opened. The `$_SESSION['id']` is then set to the NEWER page. When refresh OLDER page, it'll reload as the one seen on the NEWER page because of the `$_SESSION['id']` variable set on the latest action.

How do I go about tackling this issue?
Any potential problems using the method you suggested?

Please assist with some input!

EDIT: If down-voted, please let me know how I can adjust the question so its more clear.

EDIT: Changed out `$_SESSION['create']` to `$_SESSION['id']` to better reflect the question

Comment: you can not use same session name for different values. it will overwrite value with newest one

Comment: What do you want to happen when the user loads the new page?  Perhaps trying to do some [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) may help.

Comment: When user loads the new page, will be exactly how it should, all fields are blank. Issue happens only if user opens two of the same page. i.e. Stackoverflow asking a question, you open another one and edit it, the old question is lost on refresh

Comment: Is there a reason you need to save anything in a session? Why not send parameters in the query to create.php?  like `create.php?id=5` and use `id` to display the correct data instead of the session value

Comment: I don't think I should've posted this question.. someone is putting negative votes on everything. 
I thought about using '?id=5' but the user won't have a seamless experience and user altering that id requires additional logic in the backend when programming... if that is the only way, then I guess I can just go that route. Thank you for the feedback. @binnyb

Comment: @webdeveloper The idea is to get others input on how I should go about designing the page. I want to allow user to "store" information when using "CREATE" link. On additional "CREATE", that stored information can be saved separately. Don't stress too much about the identical $_SESSION, because that wasn't the focus of the question.

Answer (score -1):

While creating session check if the session already exists or not

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['create'])){
    // create session if it doesnt exists.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I wasn't really looking for how to create a session check.